# How to retrieve cluster-keys in vault if it lost?

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I have generated the root token during the initialization of the vault using following command.

```
$ kubectl exec vault-0 -- vault operator init \                                       
    -key-shares=1 \        
    -key-threshold=1 \
    -format=json > cluster-keys.json
```

However, I have lost the file `cluster-keys.json`.

Is it possible to get the `cluster-keys.json` content again without re-initializing?

Comment: The unseal keys cannot be regenerated post-initialization. You will have to re-initialize the server cluster. Note a root token can be regenerated though after revocation.

Comment: It's better to write this in an answer, not in a comment, isn't it?